# How do they make transformers bigger/deeper?

Tags: transformer, gpt

I can find a million explanations of the diagram in the original transformer paper:

[image]

But I know that modern GPT models have many millions of weights. Where are they?  Or in other words, how does this thing scale?

Answer (score 2):

The diagram is a concise representation where the Nx refers to a collapsed array. This diagram can be expanded horizontally with multiple left columns chained together. This diagram can be expanded vertically with multiple yellow/orange rows chained together. If you do an image search you'll find some zoomed out color coded maps of various topologies.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a model based on the transformer that does what you say?